# SwiftUI - Toggle keyboard type (default/numeric) using Toggle switch?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikeyboard, uikeyboardtype

I am creating an application setup screen in iOS using SwiftUI, where a user will enter a password and then confirm it.  I have created a `ToolbarItemGroup` for my keyboard that will let the user toggle between a numeric password and a complex password using a `Toggle` control.  I would like to be able to toggle the `UIKeyboardType` to match the value of the `Toggle` switch, as well, but I am not seeing it update as expected.  Here's what my code looks like so far:

```
        SecureField("Master Password", text: $viewModel.password)
            .modifier(NoAutocapitalizationViewModifier())
            .padding()
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0).strokeBorder(Color.blue, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2.0)))
            .padding([.horizontal])
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .keyboardType(viewModel.isAlphaNumeric ? .default : .numberPad)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Toggle("Complex Password", isOn: $viewModel.isAlphaNumeric)
                        .toggleStyle(.switch)
                }
            }

        SecureField("Confirm Password", text: $viewModel.confirmPassword)
            .modifier(NoAutocapitalizationViewModifier())
            .padding()
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0).strokeBorder(Color.blue, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2.0)))
            .padding([.horizontal])
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .keyboardType(viewModel.isAlphaNumeric ? .default : .numberPad)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Toggle("Complex Password", isOn: $viewModel.isAlphaNumeric)
                        .toggleStyle(.switch)
                }
            }
```

As you can see, the `Toggle` updates a boolean value in my `ViewModel` object to indicate whether it is a complex password.  However, I am not seeing the change reflected in the `.keyboardType` value whenever I change the value of the switch.  If I move to the "Confirm Password" field and then move back I see the keyboard changed appropriately, but it does not happen dynamically when changing the `Toggle` value.

How can I get the `UIKeyboardType` value to change dynamically based off the value of the `Toggle` control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyboard once created can be cached, so try like the following (everywhere needed):

```
    SecureField("Confirm Password", text: $viewModel.confirmPassword)
        .modifier(NoAutocapitalizationViewModifier())
        .padding()
        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0).strokeBorder(Color.blue, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2.0)))
        .padding([.horizontal])
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .keyboardType(viewModel.isAlphaNumeric ? .default : .numberPad)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                Spacer()
                
                Toggle("Complex Password", isOn: $viewModel.isAlphaNumeric)
                    .toggleStyle(.switch)
            }
        }
        .id(viewModel.isAlphaNumeric)      // << here !!
```